# List of last X visited Stack Overflow questions between web and mobile device like unix history

Tags: feature-request

This might be one of those "it already exists" feature requests / support questions.

But is there a way to see the history of questions you've visited in Stack Overflow, maybe even like the last 100 or something similar to the unix history command?

There has been times when I've stumbled across something and need to go back to it and it is not findable via Google (and I didn't favorite) nor back button. Ideally a history by tag would be really cool.

So, I use SO on laptop / Chrome and iPad / Safari. Browser history is not sufficient.

Comment: Most, if not all browsers implement a filterable history feature. I would use that.

Comment: Is your browser's history not sufficient for this?

Comment: And this has been asked for before. More than once.

Comment: I've used Chrome's history in the past for this but find it really clunky and I tend to use safari on my ipad. I'd prefer this information were centralized.

Comment: @timpone, so hit Ctrl + H. That shows your browser's history.

Comment: Vote on the good stuff. There's a history of your votes in your profile (the “votes” tab).

Comment: thx @Gilles I get what you're saying but the more I use SO, the more I find it replaces `books on the shelf`; to be honest, this isn't a feature-request but was opened as support (meta seems really snarky about doing stuff like that).